# Differences between Lingayats and Aradhyas?

Tags: philosophy, caste-system, shaivism, other-religions, sects

Lingayat community was founded by Basavanna. What is the history of Aradhyas who are shiva followers too and they too wear lingas.

What are the differences between these communities?

Comment: Lingayat or ViraShaiva was not founded by Basava, rather he had revived it.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/In-Lingayats-what-is-the-difference-between-Aradhyas-and-Jangams-Whats-the-difference-between-Lingayats-and-Veerashaivas    kindly read this, most of the answers here explains what you inquired. Hope this helps  :)

Comment: There is no clear difference between them. I am coming from the same quora page @Chamundadas

Comment: @Hansiemithun Will try to search some reliable sources.